# How to get an XMLHttpRequest object in jquery that can be used later for another request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We can create XMLHttpRequest object and then can use it later for another request like :-

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){  } // something
xhr.send(null);
```

There will be a search box and when we enter something in it, it sends an ajax request, but if the user entered more so we will cancel that previous ajax request and create new.

If we want to send another ajax request by same object, we can create an xhr object for that search box to be sure that there will be only one ajax request at a time so if we need to send another request, will will do like :-

```
xhr.abort()
xhr.open()
xhr.send(null);
```

I'm using jQuery for portability across browsers, and I want something similar to the above, meaning an XHR (or wrapped XHR) object, that can be used again and again and can also cancel previous request.

How we can do that in jQuery ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a function to return `$.get()` , `.abort()`

```
var current;
var request = function(url) {current = $.get(url); return current};
request(url); current.abort();
request(url).then(function(data) {
  // do stuff
}, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  // do stuff with error
});
```

Comment: we can also put that current.abort() in request function as well, ? so to create new request we will do like : current.abort(), current = $.get... ? right ?

Comment: @Tiger _"so to create new request we will do like : current.abort(), current = $.get... ? right ?"_ Not certain interpret correctly ? Yes, could redfine `current` as `$.get(url)`